# css 3d transforms and zindex fighting

Tags: css, 3d, z-index

I have two `<div>` elements that overlap eachother, like:

```
 -------------
 |           |
 |     A     |
 |           |
 |   ------------
 |   |          |
 |   |          |
 ----|     B    |
     |          |
     ------------
```

So I add B to the DOM after A.  Inside div A I have some other html elements (images) that I apply css3d transforms to, however when I do this they also appear infront of div B, I always want div B to be above div A and all of its content.  I tried setting the z-index property on both div elements but the 3d transformed items in A still render ontop of div B.

Any way to always make B appear infront of A and it's content?

Thanks
Mark.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the transform itself. You can try setting !important to your z-index rule on the A div. The children will inherit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an elements's `z-index` to work against 3d transformed divs, you have to style it with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);`

Snippet on codepen -> http://codepen.io/mrmoje/pen/yLIul

Answer (score 0):

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/qkLWH/1/

Comment: Seems like this puts B as a child of A (different from OP's DOM structure).